# Web Application Templates

Tags: html, web-applications, templates, user-interface

I'm looking for templates that are made specifically for web applications

### List of Web Application Templates

**PAID**

[Theme Forest - Cheap, a lot to choose from](http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-templates)

[Gooey Templates](http://www.gooeytemplates.com/)

<s>[Get A DevBox](http://www.getadevbox.com/)</s> (unavailable)

**FREE**

[Bloganje](http://www.bloganje.com/free-admin-template.html) (Not Working)

[Transdmin](https://github.com/zapnap/transdmin)

[WebResourcesDepot](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-admin-template-for-web-applications/)

Comment: See : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522856/what-are-good-resources-for-css-templates-or-templated-layout-sites>

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme is absolutely stunning and actively developed. :)

Comment: wish I did rails and not PHP lol....that looks very nice and it's just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The WebResourcesDepot one is developed by me.

However, personally, I'm using http://www.admintemplates.com for my projects which has a buy-once, use-always license which is far cheaper than ThemeForest's extended licenses.

It has a very simple, flexible code and not-bloated like many others.

Comment: The project is now dead.