# iPhone/Android WebApp Templates

Tags: android, iphone, html, web-applications

Are there any ready-made mobile HTML5/CSS3 templates available on the net (for webapps). I don't want to have a native look nor want a native look with webapps. But I want kewl eye-catching designs with a lot of colors. As I'm a developer I'm a super noob at designing. Let me know if you guys use any resources.

P.S.To be specific I needed it for holding two countdowns (placeholders) & 2 images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually look at DeviantArt for UI ideas,

http://browse.deviantart.com/?qh=&section=&q=iphone+app+template

From there you could find one you like and code it.

Also look at this link for a backbone template,

http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

A simple google search would have led you here...

[Web Application Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561731/web-application-templates)